# Can't resize the image in navbar

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm making a site for a project and can't resize or change anything in a logo that I have.
I don't really know what am I doing wrong.

Here's the part with html and when I try to select the logo in css , it won't change in any way.( I've tried to change it's position to the right of navbar,but it still sticks to the left)

```css
*{    
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

}

.logo {
  float: right;

}

header {
background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0,auto;
  padding: 0,auto;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2ex;
  padding: 5ex;

}

nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4ex;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <div id="wrapper">
    
       <div id="imports">     
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">
                  
       </div>
    
        <header>
                <div id="menu">
    
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png" alt="logo">
         
                <home>                  
                    <nav class="menu">                          
                        <ol>                   
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </home>
    
               </div>
       </header> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your `.logo` class is missing from `img`

```
<img src="Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

Answer (score -1):

give `img` tag `logo` class

```
<img src="Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: Make sure you format your answer properly. You can also copy the snipped from the question to verify the answer yourself.